# Airflow Error Calling split function on param

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2

I have an Airflow DAG running a `KubernetesPodOperator` task. I'd like to create a parameter that appends an array of params to the `cmds` argument of `KubernetesPodOperator`.

Ideally I'd like this parameter to return a native Python list. However, currently I have it returning a string, and I attempt to call the split() function on the string. The split() seems to run *before* the Jinja template evaluates, so I get this error message:

```
ERROR - Exception rendering Jinja template for task 'example-task', field 'cmds'. Template: ['dbt', 'run-operation', 'stage_external_sources', '{{', 'params.extra_params', '}}']
```

Besides direct answers, I'm also interested in suggestions of how I could approach this differently--is there another way to pass this parameter besides using the Jinja template syntax?

I am running Airflow 2.5.2 in Docker using Astro (Astronomer Runtime 7.4.0).

Below is the full (simplified) code of my script, along with the full error output.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.param import Param
from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import (
    KubernetesPodOperator,
)

with DAG(
    "dbt-example",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 7, 20),
    schedule_interval="0 7 * * *",
    catchup=False,
    default_args={"retries": 0},
    max_active_runs=1,
    params={
        "extra_params": Param(
            default="--target prod",
            description="extra params to attach to dbt",
        ),
    },
) as dag:
    extra_params = "{{ params.extra_params }}"

    KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace=conf.get("kubernetes_executor", "NAMESPACE"),
        image=f"cv-dbt-treehouse:localtest",
        task_id="example-task",
        name="dbt-stage-sources",
        random_name_suffix=True,
        config_file="/usr/local/airflow/include/.kube/config",
        cmds=f"dbt run-operation stage_external_sources {extra_params}".strip().split(),
        get_logs=True,
    )
```

Full log output:

```
*** Reading local file: /usr/local/airflow/logs/dag_id=dbt-example/run_id=manual__2023-08-30T03:19:13+00:00/task_id=example-task/attempt=1.log
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1084} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: dbt-example.example-task manual__2023-08-30T03:19:13+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1084} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: dbt-example.example-task manual__2023-08-30T03:19:13+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1282} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1283} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1284} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1303} INFO - Executing <Task(KubernetesPodOperator): example-task> on 2023-08-30 03:19:13+00:00
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 421 to run task
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'dbt-example', 'example-task', 'manual__2023-08-30T03:19:13+00:00', '--job-id', '1226', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/example.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpwgloylen']
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 1226: Subtask example-task
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {task_command.py:388} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: dbt-example.example-task manual__2023-08-30T03:19:13+00:00 [running]> on host dab567621c61
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {abstractoperator.py:611} ERROR - Exception rendering Jinja template for task 'example-task', field 'cmds'. Template: ['dbt', 'run-operation', 'stage_external_sources', '{{', 'params.extra_params', '}}']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 603, in _do_render_template_fields
    rendered_content = self.render_template(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 676, in render_template
    return [self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 676, in <listcomp>
    return [self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 661, in render_template
    template = jinja_env.from_string(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1105, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), gs, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 768, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected 'end of template'
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1775} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1377, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context, test_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1495, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    task_orig = self.render_templates(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2122, in render_templates
    original_task.render_template_fields(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1179, in render_template_fields
    self._do_render_template_fields(self, self.template_fields, context, jinja_env, set())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 603, in _do_render_template_fields
    rendered_content = self.render_template(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 676, in render_template
    return [self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 676, in <listcomp>
    return [self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 661, in render_template
    template = jinja_env.from_string(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1105, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), gs, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 768, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected 'end of template'
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1321} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=dbt-example, task_id=example-task, execution_date=20230830T031913, start_date=20230830T031923, end_date=20230830T031923
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:100} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1226 for task example-task (unexpected 'end of template'; 421)
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {local_task_job.py:212} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-08-30, 03:19:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2585} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```